# How to check which @route triggered Controller::Action in Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, routes

In Symfony2 it is possible to define 2 different `@routes` to get one same *Controller* and *Action*?

The thing is: how do you check in that unique action what path or route does the user come from?

**Example:** Imagine we have an action called `"createUserAction"` that can be reached both from `@routes /common_register` and `/premium_register`.

Inside the action I want to difference between the two kinds of users, to use different forms and create the users according to the route they have entered through (or in general, have a different behavour depending o it).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your action, just add additional special route parameter `$_route` to the method

```
public function createUserAction ($_route)
{
    ... //$_route will return the name of your route
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered another approach? Just use a single route with a parameter:

```
/**
 *@route ("/register/{type}", requirements={"type" = "common|premium"})
 **/

public function createUserAction ($type) {
    //use $type to decide what to do
}
```